# Is there a way to make react-native ignore some files that not to bundle them?

Tags: android, react-native

I already had a project which based on React for Web. And now, I created a React-Native project here. If I bundle with `react-native bundle`, react-native will bundle all my files then prompt lots of WARNING. So I want to make react-native ignore files under `/www`.

I tried these actions, but useless:

1. Add my paths to `sharedBlacklistWildcards` in `node_modules/react-native/packager/blacklist.js`.
2. Add my paths to `.flowconfig`.

I checked the documentation, but didn't find anything useful. How could I do that, or if I have a wrong idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963217/2959392

Comment: @zsx I am also looking the same. Did you able to manage to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I modified the file in the `node_modules/react-native`. It's the only way I found so far, and I'm still looking forward to a better solution.

`node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\DependencyResolver\fastfs.js` is used to scan files. So I rewrited `File::getFiles` to this:

```js
  getFiles() {
    return _.flatten(_.values(this.children).filter(
        file => !/platforms$|www$/.test(file.path)
      ).map(file => {
        if (file.isDir) {
          return file.getFiles();
        } else {
          return file;
        }
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Did you get any better solution for this. I am also having same problem