# How to make Metro (React Native packager) ignore certain directories

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Problem:

My project has a `@providesModule naming collision` when trying to run `react-native run-ios` from the command line. It is conflicting with autogenerated dir `dist/` which is created by another npm package, esdoc. I would like to be able to keep this autogenerated dir and just make the react native packager ignore the `dist/` dir.

Error Message:

```
[01/23/2017, 13:17:07] <START> Building Haste Map
    Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
      Duplicate module name: ann
      Paths: /Users/thurt/projects/example/package.json collides with /Users/thurt/projects/example/dist/esdoc/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: ann
  Paths: /Users/thurt/projects/example/package.json collides with /Users/thurt/projects/example/dist/esdoc/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/Users/thurt/projects/example/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:158:13)
    at p.getName.then.name (/Users/thurt/projects/example/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:133:31)
```

Comment: hello just came across this post for my issue, i am using 0.59.8 react-native version, i have two metro.config.js files one under node-module/metro and another under node-module/react-native which to change? plz help struggling with issue past 3 days

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The configuration for this has a habit of changing between RN versions. See below for version-specific instructions on creating a config file, loading the config file and clearing the cache.

**For React Native >= 0.64 to 0.71(+?)**

*A rename of the helper function [from `blacklist` to `exclusionList` was made in Metro 0.60](https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/3e2d9116d8a7f2580dcda51990cca5b3d98a81ff), and the config entry [`blacklistRE` -> `blockList` in Metro 0.61](https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/94c0b541b4bfa17aee4efa0f1969565522ce830d). These both [landed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.64-stable/package.json) in RN in 0.64.0.*

In your project root create `metro.config.js` with the contents:

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

// exclusionList is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default exclusions to return a single regex.

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blockList: exclusionList([/dist\/.*/])
  }
};
```

**For React Native >= 0.59, < 0.64**

In your project root create `metro.config.js` with the contents:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

// blacklist is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default blacklist to return a single regex.

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/dist\/.*/])
  }
};
```

**For React Native >= 0.57, < 0.59**

In your project root create `rn-cli.config.js` with the contents:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

// blacklist is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default blacklist to return a single regex.

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/dist\/.*/])
  }
};
```

**For React Native >= 0.52, < 0.57**

In your project root create `rn-cli.config.js` with the contents:

```
const blacklist = require('metro').createBlacklist;

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE: function() {
    return blacklist([/dist\/.*/]);
  }
};
```

**For React Native >= 0.46, < 0.52**.

In your project root create `rn-cli.config.js` with the contents:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-bundler').createBlacklist;

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE: function() {
    return blacklist([/dist\/.*/]);
  }
};
```

**For React Native < 0.46**.

In your project root create `rn-cli.config.js` with the contents:

```
const blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE: function() {
    return blacklist([/dist\/.*/]);
  }
};
```

**All versions < 0.59**

Have your CLI command use this config by passing the `--config` option:

`react-native run-ios --config=rn-cli.config.js`

(The config file should be automatically picked up by RN >= 0.59, ever since it was renamed `metro.config.js`)

**All versions: Note on caching**

Be aware that your blacklisted items may have already been included in the cache by the packager in which case the first time you run the packager with the blacklist you may need to reset the cache with `--reset-cache`

Comment: Thanks rob ! For my situation, all I needed to do was include the `--reset-cache` flag. now it appears that my `rn-cli.config.js` file is automatically used, so i did not need the `--config=rn-cli.config.js`.


After successfully getting past the packager step, I was still getting "module not found" error when app first tries to load up.


I added the project folder name to the beginning of the blacklist regex which appears to fix that problem. I think I needed that to ensure the packager does not ignore folders like <projectdir>/node_modules/<module>/dist/

Comment: which rn version do you use?

Comment: @GuySegal rn 0.40.0

Comment: What is NOT said here is that the matching is anchored to the end of input (the regular expressions in the array are built into one final regular expression that is terminated by $)... so make sure to put a .* at the end of the regular expression you would like to match against. Also, another helpful hint is that all '/' forward slashes are automatically replaced with the current OS path separator.

Comment: As of (at least) RN 0.52, the import needs to be: `const blacklist = require('metro').createBlacklist;`

Comment: @mtkopone good spot. `metro-bundler` was renamed `metro` in RN 0.52.0 exactly. Will update the answer.

Comment: This is not working for me, seems like getBlacklistRE ignoring my regex.

Comment: @sunny have you reset the pacakager cache? If you want to post your RN version and code as a new question I’ll try to help.

Comment: @RobHogan I have already posted as a new question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383954/blacklisting-react-native-module-doesnt-works

Comment: does this work for you in mac as well ? I am using ReactNative version 0.56 and I have tried the same solution suggested here. But no luck. I am doing iOS app with RN.

Comment: @YugandharPathi I've updated my answer for RN 0.57 - maybe you could try that version with 0.56?

Comment: did not work with rn-cli.config.js but perfectly works with the same changes made in metro.config.js ("react-native": "0.59.4", windows)

Comment: `metro.config.js` is a new name of this config file, `rn-cli.config.js` is a legacy name. And there is no need to pass it to `--config` option.

Comment: @KEMBL @zubko - thanks, I've updated for RN 0.59+ and `metro.config.js`

Comment: hello just came across this post for my issue, i am using 0.59.8 react-native version, i have two metro.config.js files one under node-module/metro and another under node-module/react-native which to change? plz help struggling with issue past 3 days

Comment: @user2813740 don’t modify anything under `node_modules`. As the answer says, you need to create a *new* `metro.config.js` in your project root (that’s the top level directory which also contains your `package.json` etc)

Comment: @Rob Hogan hello, i tried earlier,  now also i tried but getting same issue. i am totally new for react native without prior java-script experience ....... how does i have to tell project refer to created metro.config.js? mine i have created Expo CLI project and added backend. please help...totally lost

Comment: @Rob Hogan, as my project shows already two metro.config.js so dont know if new added filed picked up or not i am using all latest versions only

Comment: Ignoring directories with the packager (this question and answer) is a fairly unusual use case that shouldn't be necessary with Expo out of the box. My guess is this probably isn't the right solution to whatever problem you're having. If you want to create a new question with the original problem that led you to try this, post a link here and I'll take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838038/haste-module-naming-collision-react-native-app-with-aws-service-amplify-projec             i had added question but i did not got any answer...plz have a look

Comment: In recent versions of Metro, this is called `blocklist`. See https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/591

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury - thanks, but `inlineRequires` isn't the option covered by this answer. However, the exported function in `defaults` has actually renamed from `blacklist` to `exclusionList` in metro 0.60. I've added a section on RN 0.64+ covering this.

Comment: Thanks for adding the 0.64 update.  I have tested and it works.

Comment: At least with 0.70.3, it seems wrong to use "exclusionList" with blacklistRE.  All that does is replace directory separators, changing / to \ in Windows, but the code that uses this pattern (anymatch) always expects forward slashes.  Just using a regex directly works for me.  Maybe they're meant to be used together and this is a bug (don't have time to investigate further).

Comment: @GlennMaynard - I think you might be right - I suspect the default exclusion list (which covers things like `.git`) may actually be ineffective on Windows, which is a bug. That may be harmless, but probably means Metro is watching more files than it needs to.

(PSA: Since my last comment here, I joined FB/Meta and I'm now maintaining Metro :) )

Answer (score 1):

For [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro):

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  ...config,
  resolver: {
    ...config.resolver,
    blockList: [config.resolver.blockList, /(\/amplify\/.*)$/],
  },
};
```