# Haste module naming collision: react native app with AWS Service (Amplify Project)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

i have started with react native project, earlier was in native code.
i wanted to add Amazon Lex so followed below steps from link

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions

below is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

i have just set up amplify library and added interaction for LEX, but started getting below error as i try to run app. before adding was working fine...once Amplify folder got created with back-end error started.....

> (node:26180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map:
>   Haste module naming collision:   Duplicate module name:
>   myamplifyproject_cfnlambda_87887b9a   Paths:
>   C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\amplify\backend\interactions\lex900662fd\src\package.json
>   collides with
>   C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\amplify#current-cloud-backend\interactions\lex900662fd\src\package.json
>
> This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for
>   different files.
>       at setModule (C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:569:17)
>       at workerReply (C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:641:9)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>       at async Promise.all (index 30) ERROR 18:24 (node:26180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:26180) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:26180)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module
>   naming collision:   Duplicate module name:
>   myamplifyproject_cfnlambda_87887b9a   Paths:
>   C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\amplify\backend\interactions\lex900662fd\src\package.json
>   collides with
>   C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\amplify#current-cloud-backend\interactions\lex900662fd\src\package.json
>
> This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for
>   different files.
>       at setModule (C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:569:17)
>       at workerReply (C:\Users\temp\Desktop\myAmplifyProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:641:9)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>       at async Promise.all (index 30) (node:26180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

i have used all latest versions for react-native.

i tried below solution but not working [how to make react native packager ignore certain directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813211/how-to-make-react-native-packager-ignore-certain-directories/41963217?noredirect=1#comment104046098_41963217)

i just follwed steps ...where i am going wrong....missing anything....
Please help...this is my first app in react native.... i am actually lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after lots of sleepless nights and testing different solution i finally able to get through..i am using latest react-native > 0.59 (i guess 0.61)
my app already created metro.config.js file at the root directory, one has to edit same.

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');   // on top

resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/])         //add within module export  
  }
```

and i took fresh air...now everything works fine...

please do not create new metro.config.js or rn-cli.config.js. edit present metro.config.js with **#current-cloud-backend** not **backend** folder. this is very important.
backend will be ignored....

this will help someone in future....as nothing works which ever solutions are given....for latest react native.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. My previous solution was to remove the package.json files from the #current-cloud-backend folder, but it's quite manual and error-prone.

Comment: editing metro.config.js keeps resulting in 'unable to resolve crypto in crypto-js' error for me