# React native : Failed to construct transformer: Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters

Tags: node.js, react-native

[image: hear is the screenshot of the error]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.1.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.6.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.40",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

i did't fonund any answers related this except this : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28189

but it won't work for me...

myapp **successfully install on android emulator** but stuck at *splash screen* ...

the app **works fine in my office computer** but it *did't work on my own computer*

my **node version** : *v14.10.0*

so please help me.

Comment: You can probably add full error stack as well in your question.

Comment: ok, next time i remember this.

Comment: actually i have create whole project from scratch, but i would love to see solution if anyone have

Answer (score 20):

I've tried to log the file that causing the error, but console.log wasn't working.
I come up with a quick hack to `throw filePath` then I've saw that **a zip file, that I keeped as a backup, was the issue.**

For some way react doesn't liked it so **I have to move it outside of the project folder**

Comment: Where did you place this throw filePath? Inside worker.js from jest-haste-map module? Or..?

Comment: @Dirk, If you have any zip folder inside your project folder just remove it from there and save it somewhere else. I had same issue and this helped me.

Comment: For me it was the android folder somehow. I removed it and the build worked for iOS.

Comment: Thanks! I too had a zip file, which got created for me in
android/app/build/intermediates/module_bundle/productionRelease/base.zip

Answer (score 5):

For others having the same problem, and looking for a way to debug:

- Edit `/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js`
- Wrap `readFileSync` in a `try...catch`, like this:

```
  const getContent = () => {
    if (content === undefined) {
      try {
        content = fs().readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`error readFileSync ${filePath} : ${err.message}`);
      }
    }

    return content;
  };
```

- (re)start metro bundler:

`/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command; exit`

My output:

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error readFileSync <my project path>/some/big/file/that/caused/error : Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
    at getContent (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:133:15)
    at Object.worker (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:162:23)
    at execFunction (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:145:17)
    at execHelper (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:124:5)
    at execMethod (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:128:5)
    at process.messageListener (<my project path>/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js:46:7)
    at process.emi
```

Hope this helps others having the same problem!

Comment: Thank you - this revealed a ZIP file in my Android build directory that I have no clue (yet) how it ended up there.

Comment: You’re welcome, glad some effort helps at least one 

Comment: Super thanks, this revealed a zip file in my Android build directory too, and same here, no clue how it got there. Following was its location (if it help anyone)
android/app/build/intermediates/module_bundle/productionRelease/base.zip

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem.

```
 warning: the transform cache was reset.                                                                          
                 Welcome to React Native!                                                                        
                Learn once, write anywhere 
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters                
    at Object.slice (buffer.js:608:37)                                                                           
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:805:14)                                                                        
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:421:41)                                                                        
    at getContent (J:\expoProjects\rn-cnn\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:149:41) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (J:\expoProjects\rn-cnn\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:
199:9)                                                                                                           
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)                                                                              
    at asyncGeneratorStep (J:\expoProjects\rn-cnn\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:
78:24)                                                                                                           
    at _next (J:\expoProjects\rn-cnn\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:98:9)        
    at J:\expoProjects\rn-cnn\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:103:7               
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {                                                                               
  type: 'Error',                                                                                                 
  code: 'ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG'
```

I solved the error by changing the node version to v14+ and then reverting back to the old version of node v10.15.3.

Comment: I recreated the project and add all screens and files manually because at that time I don't find any answers.
by the way, thank you for the answer it helps someone who faces this type of error

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the exact same error. Turns out it was an auto-generated big file from gradle (> 700MB) inside "android.gradle\6.0.1\executionHistory"

Answer (score 3):

To figure out what file caused an error I used @dirk approach.
I don't sure why but my App_name.app.dSYM.zip became too large (536MB) so the node was unable to read it because of the 512MB limitation. It might be some different file in your case.
Here is a patch-package to get more information about the file which caused this error

```
diff --git a/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js b/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js
index 1996d4a..1f17f11 100644
--- a/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js
+++ b/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js
@@ -146,7 +146,11 @@ function _worker() {
 
     const getContent = () => {
       if (content === undefined) {
-        content = _gracefulFs().default.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
+        try {
+          content = _gracefulFs().default.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
+        } catch (err) {
+          throw new Error(`error readFileSync ${filePath} : ${err.message}`);
+        }
       }
 
       return content;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if there any unrelated file or zip in your project structure/folder
if yes then delete file and error will be resolved

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any large files in your root project including (mp4, images, .zip, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Moving any large asset files [pictures,videos,etc...] up out of the project directory.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28189#issuecomment-592918995

Answer (score 1):

In my own case I noticed I was using an mp4 video file for my react native application which was too large in size. I had to delete it and that was the fix for me

Answer (score 1):

It took me the whole day but I solved it. I still can't understand why I'm getting this error when I want to launch the app on iOS but:

removing the `build` directory in android/app fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a zip file of whole project in the project directory which cause the issue when I remove it from the project directory and run

```
npm start --reset cache
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. After some debugging I found that it crashes because of asset file, which was generated by android build previously.

I don't know why it is trying to import this file (I experience this issue on ios), but when I removed folder `./android/app/build` it started working.

Even if issue is not related to this dir in your case, you need to find which asset caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i run build.

But This fix worked for me.
I deleted a zip file at the root of my app (I compressed the whole project to zip at end of the previous day for backup)

And i stopped the server with ctr + c command
Then restarted the server with npx react-native start

All now works fine after restarting the server and without having to run build again.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete any zipped file in your project root directory. In my case I had packaged the app and sent it to someone and forgot to remove the  zipped file thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963217/2915928

For my case my app had a lot of audio files being included in android app bundle, this was then creating a large zip file in android/build/intermediates. So rather than deleting the build folder this tell the packager to ignore the file causing the issue.

Here is an example of my fix replace `asset_pack_bundle` with whatever file or directory you are having an issue with.

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: exclusionList([/asset_pack_bundle\/.*/]),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below steps and it worked for me:

**1. cleared cache and unnecessary space from my mac.**

**2. cleared npm cache and watchman.**

**3. cleared gradle.**

**4. restarted the metro server.**

Answer (score 0):

in my ***android/.gradlew/7.5.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin***
was causing issue as it was 590mbs and was unreadable,

**Solved:**
Deleted ***executionHistory.bin*** and rerun the metro server//rebuild the app and it created a new file with smaller file size!