# Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters in Nodejs Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, buffer

I am getting a buffer data from frontend to nodejs as below

```
 <Buffer 53 6f 75 72 63 65 53 63 68 65 6d 61 2c 43 6f 75 6e 74 72 79 4e 61 6d 65 2c 49 44 2c 41 4d 54 5f 45 58 43 4c 5f 54 41 58 2c 41 4d 54 5f 49 4e 43 4c 5f ... 340629006 more bytes>
```

I am trying to save this data to database using sequelize as below

```
const DBMODEL = require("../../../models/SaveBufferData")

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

try{
var bufdata = req.file.buffer;
var response = await DBMODEL.SaveBufferData(req.body.fileId, bufdata);

} catch (error) {
   console.log('errorerror',error)
   res.status(500).json(ResponseManager(false, error.message));
 }
```

I am getting an error as below

```
node:buffer:669
slice: (buf, start, end) => buf.hexSlice(start, end),
                                ^

Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
    at Object.slice (node:buffer:669:37)
    at Buffer.toString (node:buffer:811:14)
    at BLOB._stringify (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\data-types.js:423:23)
    at BLOB.stringify (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\data-types.js:22:19)
    at escape (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:40:48)
    at C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:101:14
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Object.formatNamedParameters (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:96:14)
    at Object.formatNamedParameters (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\utils.js:112:20)
    at Sequelize.query (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sequelize.js:283:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG'
}
```

Why am I getting this error? can anyone please explain

Comment: you're getting this error because apparently the string you are trying to make is longer than 536,870,888 characters - you should've searched stack overflow ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230031/cannot-create-a-string-longer-than-0x1fffffe8-characters-in-json-parse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493636/cannot-create-a-string-longer-than-0x1fffffe8-characters-in-react-native https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840115/react-native-failed-to-construct-transformer-error-cannot-create-a-string-lo ... there's MANY questions (and answers)

Comment: @Bravo So what is the solution? I have to save it to db for future use

Comment: I believe you should not store such large object in DB. Instead, use some storage e.g. S3

Comment: I dont have an s3 option, I have to save it in db

Comment: Perhaps one of the other questions on this topic has an answer. Research

Comment: I have done a research I didnt find anything related to db. Can u provide the link please

Comment: @Bravo or do u have any suggestions other than db and s3?

Comment: other than db? you said you HAVE to save in db ... did you search and read all the answers - there isn't really that many on stack overflow, but surely someone else tried to do what you want

Comment: @Bravo Yes, I have to save it in DB. in worst case if I cant I have to look for an alternative. I have searched in google for the solution, yes even I didnt find many questions in google. also I didnt find the solution for it, thats the reason I have posted a question here.

Comment: The answer is, don't save the data as a string to the "db" - what other data formats does the "db" accept? Perhaps a BLOB

Comment: whatever formats are available for sql server, it can be saved in that format. Also we must be able to convert back to the buffer format at nodejs level in future after fetching.

Comment: then a BLOB is what you want Binary Large OBject - and yes, retrieving a blob results in a buffer

Comment: How to do it? How to convert to blob?

Comment: @Bravo Or can we save buffer data to a file?