# AWS Amplify Duplicate Error: Duplicated files or mocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I set up a new amplify, added auth, and a post confirmation lambda function to move user data into DynamoDB. When I run NPM start, I get this error:

> Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
> at setModule (\MyDemo\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:543:17)
> .js:426:22 {

> mockPath1: 'amplify#current-cloud-backend\function\FreshAuthPostConfirmation\src\package.json',

> mockPath2: 'amplify\backend\function\FreshAuthPostConfirmation\src\package.json'
> }
> '''

Based on what I have read, #current-cloud-backend gets created by amplify, based on the files in the backend folder. It seems like that package.json is supposed to be there, but I am not sure why it is an error. I saw somewhere that I should just delete the subclass duplicate file, which I assumed to be the one in #current-cloud-backend, but amplify is going to keep producing this error every time I push to it, how do I avoid this from happening at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a discussion about this error in this [Amplify GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3295). The file `package.json` appears twice to jest-haste-map, and the solution is to explicitly  ignore the `#current-cloud-backend` folder when building and starting your app.

The solution to the problem depends on your version of React Native: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813211/how-to-make-react-native-packager-ignore-certain-directories/41963217#41963217) you find an overview of how exlusion of files work for different versions. For example, you can create a `metro.config.js` file with the following contents to exclude the `#current-cloud-backend`:

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: exclusionList([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/])
  }
};
```

And install `metro-config` as a dev dependency. If that doesn't work there are some other solutions in the links that you can try out.

Comment: I am about to walk to class, I will take a look at this asap and award you accordingly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem. I'm using Expo SDK 48 and Amplify with lambda functions
To add metro.config.js file into expo project, follow: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/

1. run `npx expo customize metro.config.js` in project terminal
2. inside generated metro.config.js file, modify it to:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.resolver.blacklistRE = exclusionList([/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]);

module.exports = config;
```

No need to install any extra npm packages (I see some answers ask you to install metro-confic dev dependencies, which is not needed according to my experiment, it even brought EAS build failures...)

Then I tried `npx expo start` and `eas build -p ios`, both works successfully.

Comment: This worked for me and is much simpler than the other solution!